# pretty-printing OrderedDicts using pprint

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, pprint

I'm using `pprint` to nicely print a `dict` and it's working fine.  Now I switch to using an `OrderedDict` from module `collections`.  Unfortunately, the `pprint` routing does not seem to recognize that such objects are more or less `dict`s as well and falls back to printing that as a long line.

```
>>> d = { i:'*'*i for i in range(8) }
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{0: '',
 1: '*',
 2: '**',
 3: '***',
 4: '****',
 5: '*****',
 6: '******',
 7: '*******'}
>>> pprint.pprint(collections.OrderedDict(d))
OrderedDict([(0, ''), (1, '*'), (2, '**'), (3, '***'), (4, '****'), (5, '*****'), (6, '******'), (7, '*******')])
```

Any way to get a nicer representation of `OrderedDict`s as well?  Maybe even if they are nested *inside* a normal `dict` or `list`?

Answer (score 3):

I found a relatively simple solution for this, but it includes the risk of making the output for your ordered dictionary appear exactly as if it were a regular `dict` object.

The original solution for using a context manager to prevent `pprint` from sorting dictionary keys comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688431/3637954).

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def pprint_OrderedDict():
    pp_orig = pprint._sorted
    od_orig = OrderedDict.__repr__
    try:
        pprint._sorted = lambda x:x
        OrderedDict.__repr__ = dict.__repr__
        yield
    finally:
        pprint._sorted = pp_orig
        OrderedDict.__repr__ = od_orig
```

(You could also just patch the `OrderedDict.__repr__` method with `dict.__repr__`, but please don't.)

Example:

```
>>> foo = [('Roger', 'Owner'), ('Diane', 'Manager'), ('Bob', 'Manager'),
...        ('Ian', 'Associate'), ('Bill', 'Associate'), ('Melinda', 'Associate')]

>>> d = OrderedDict(foo)
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
OrderedDict([('Roger', 'Owner'), ('Diane', 'Manager'), ('Bob', 'Manager'), ('Ian', 'Associate'), ('Bill', 'Associate'), ('Melinda', 'Associate')])

>>> pprint.pprint(dict(d))
{'Bill': 'Associate',
 'Bob': 'Manager',
 'Diane': 'Manager',
 'Ian': 'Associate',
 'Melinda': 'Associate',
 'Roger': 'Owner'}

>>> with pprint_OrderedDict():
...     pprint.pprint(d)
...
{'Roger': 'Owner',
 'Diane': 'Manager',
 'Bob': 'Manager',
 'Ian': 'Associate',
 'Bill': 'Associate',
 'Melinda': 'Associate'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this on:

`d = collections.OrderedDict({ i:'*'*i for i in range(8) })`

**EDIT**

`pprint.pprint(list(d.items()))`

Comment: Yeah, well, okay.  This then looks like a list of tuples, not like a `dict` anymore.  I was hoping for a representation which still looked like a dict (and maybe just ignored the fact that this was an ordered one).

Comment: I think you can even strip the `list` around those `d.items()`.  But I still wonder why the `pprint` even has such a problem with `OrderedDict`s; after all they are inherting `dict`.

Comment: Ah, I thought it didn't matter if it was in a list based on "Maybe even if they are nested inside a normal dict or list?"

Comment: No, that just meant that I also consider pretty printing things like `{ 3: OrderedDict(…) }`.

Comment: I see. Off the top of my head I can't think of another way to do it. Why not forgo using `pprint` and loop through the OrderedDict and format the output yourself?

Comment: I'm using `pprint` to output a large tree structure, and one part deep inside that is an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Alfe: That's because the implementation of `pprint` checks not only if the object is a `dict` (via `isinstance`), but also if the the class of the object (`OrderedDict` in this case) has the same `__repr__` method as `dict`. Any other classes that inherit from `dict` but do not override their `__repr__` method should be treated the same as `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically targeting CPython* 3.6 or later, then you can [just use regular dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict) instead of `OrderedDict`.  You'll miss out on a few [methods exclusive to `OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), and this is not (yet) guaranteed to be portable to other Python implementations,** but it is probably the simplest way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

* CPython is the reference implementation of Python which may be downloaded from python.org.
** CPython [stole this idea from PyPy](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html), so you can probably depend on it working there too.

Comment: Interesting!  But currently they say it should not be relied upon until the language specs change which can happen in the future.  So well, hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is sort of necroposting, but I thought I'd post what I use. Its main virtue is that its aoutput can be read back into python, thus allowing, for instance, to shutlle between representations (which I use, for instance, on JSON files). Of course it breaks pprint encapsulation, by ripping some code off its inner _format function.

```
#!/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import pprint;
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import sys


class MyPP (pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level):
        if not isinstance(object, OrderedDict) :
            return pprint.PrettyPrinter._format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
        level = level + 1
        objid = id(object)
        if objid in context:
            stream.write(_recursion(object))
            self._recursive = True
            self._readable = False
            return
        write = stream.write
        _len=len
        rep = self._repr(object, context, level - 1)
        typ = type(object)
        sepLines = _len(rep) > (self._width - 1 - indent - allowance)

        if self._depth and level > self._depth:
            write(rep)
            return

        write('OrderedDict([\n%s'%(' '*(indent+1),))
        if self._indent_per_level > 1:
            write((self._indent_per_level - 1) * ' ')
        length = _len(object)
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if length:
            context[objid] = 1
            indent = indent + self._indent_per_level
            items = object.items()
            key, ent = items[0]
            rep = self._repr(key, context, level)
            write('( ')
            write(rep)
            write(', ')
            self._format(ent, stream, indent + _len(rep) + 2,
                         allowance + 1, context, level)
            write(' )')
            if length > 1:
                for key, ent in items[1:]:
                    rep = self._repr(key, context, level)
                    if sepLines:
                        write(',\n%s( %s , ' % (' '*indent, rep))
                    else:
                        write(', ( %s , ' % rep)
                    self._format(ent, stream, indent + _len(rep) + 2,
                                 allowance + 1, context, level)
                    write(' )')

            indent = indent - self._indent_per_level
            del context[objid]
        write('])')
        return

pp = MyPP(indent=1)
handle=open(sys.argv[1],"r")
values=json.loads(handle.read(),object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
pp.pprint(values)
```